# Target a Folder and all his child-folders/subfolders

Tags: php

My website integrates a File Manager with a member sytem.

On registration a folder named by the member's username is created and he is granted permissions into it (upload files, create folders, move files...etc) while the rest of the File Manager, including other member's folders, remain read-only.

I'm still new with Php and currently having some troubles when I want my members to still have permissions in subfolders of their main folder.
Kind of like this :

> website/filemanager/user/username1
>
> website/filemanager/user/username1/subfolder1
>
> website/filemanager/user/username1/subfolder2

I can get my members's permissions in their mainfolder by using this :

```
<?php
    $directory = $_SESSION['cwd'];
    $parent_directory = str_replace('\\', '/', dirname($directory));
    $user = $_SESSION['simple_auth']['username'];

    if ($directory == $parent_directory.'/'.$user){
        echo "permissions granted";
    }
    else {
        echo "permissions not granted";
    }
?>
```

which checks if the user is in his folder and grants him the rights (represented as the `echo "permissions granted"` in here, but so far I cannot find a way to also apply this in the subfolders.

Is there a way so that in my exemple "permissions granted" would also appear in the subfolders of the member and not only in the folder having their name ?

Hope my request was clear enough, thanks a lot for the help !

-Apatik

**Update :**

Solution was using a recursive scandir function that would `return true` when the current directory is matching one of the scanned folder.

```
function scanDirectory($userdir = '', $directory){
    $folders = glob($userdir . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($folders as $folder){
        echo($folder.'</br>');
        if (($folder == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r')) || (gator::checkPermissions('ru')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r'))) {
            return true;
        }

        $scan_result = scanDirectory($folder, $directory);

        if($scan_result) {
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);
?>

<?php if ($getprivileges == true): ?>
<p>Permissions granted.<p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at any of the suggestions in the `Related` section on the RHS of this page for techniques for how to recursively scan folders / sub-folders? Maybe you could modify one of those for your requirements? This question gets asked and answered fairly often here.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding, I actually finished this function a couple hours ago and it's now working, I indeed used a recursive scandir function !

Comment: Thanks for the indications, it should be fine now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was using a recursive scandir function that would `return true` when the current directory is matching one of the scanned folder.

```
function scanDirectory($userdir = '', $directory){
    $folders = glob($userdir . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($folders as $folder){
        echo($folder.'</br>');
        if (($folder == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r')) || (gator::checkPermissions('ru')) || ($userdir == $directory && gator::checkPermissions('r'))) {
            return true;
        }

        $scan_result = scanDirectory($folder, $directory);

        if($scan_result) {
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

scanDirectory($userdir, $directory);
?>

<?php if ($getprivileges == true): ?>
<p>Permissions granted.<p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

More details on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508752/listing-of-folders-subfolders-with-recursivedirectoryiterator).

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is scan the directory using `scandir`. It returns a array with every directory and file. Then you can execute a `foreach` to give full permissions to each file and directory.

Maybe the solution on [php.net scandir documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#110570) is something for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I actually already figured out the solution and I just finished the function a couple hours ago, and indeed I used scandir in a recursive funtion, which then returned `true` when the current directory was matching one of the "allowed folders".