# Listing of folders/subfolders with RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php

I'm using this code to get a listing of every folders/subfolders of a repertory :

```
$path = realpath($userdir);
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $filename)
{
        echo "$filename\n";
}
```

However it displays something like this, wich add dot or double dots and displays the folder twice :

> C:\wamp\www\gg\ftp\repository\user\mister.
>
> C:\wamp\www\gg\ftp\repository\user\mister..
>
> C:\wamp\www\gg\ftp\repository\user\mister\apatik.
>
> C:\wamp\www\gg\ftp\repository\user\mister\apatik..
>
> C:\wamp\www\gg\ftp\repository\user\mister\vvxcv.
>
> C:\wamp\www\gg\ftp\repository\user\mister\vvxcv..
>
> C:\wamp\www\gg\ftp\repository\user\mister\vvxcv\vcxvcx.
>
> C:\wamp\www\gg\ftp\repository\user\mister\vvxcv\vcxvcx..

Instead of something cleaner like this :

> C:\wamp\www\gg\ftp\repository\user\mister
>
> C:\wamp\www\gg\ftp\repository\user\mister\apatik
>
> C:\wamp\www\gg\ftp\repository\user\mister\vvxcv
>
> C:\wamp\www\gg\ftp\repository\user\mister\vvxcv\vcxvcx

Is there a way ? I was previously using the function glob

```
glob($sub . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

which was displaying the folder correctly but i couldn't get it to be recursive to display subfolders aswell.

Thanks

Comment: I believe `.` and `..` are considered to be directories, parent directory actually. Remove directories called `.` and `..` from the recursive function

Comment: Yeah that is also what i thought, but there is no such directories in my folder, the glob function wasn't displaying them tho :/

Comment: In linux they are there for sure and in a windows command shell you can change directory by doing a `cd ..` to the parent directory!

Comment: Throw in a `if ( $path == '.' || $path == '..' ) return;`or something such!

Comment: You need at least the `.` one as that is the actual directory. If you want to display it without the dot, you can do a `rtrim()`.

Comment: Thank you! `.` is a shortcut for **current** directory and `..` is **parent** directory. I would remove it with `substr( $path, 0, strlen( $path) - 1 )`, though.

Comment: Thanks for theses answers ! I will try theses suggestions and give an update. It's weird tho that glob() doesn't display them by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need something like this

```
set_time_limit(0);
function scanDirectory($sub = ''){
    $folders = glob($sub . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach($folders as $folder){
        echo "$folder<br />";
        scanDirectory($folder);
    }
}
scanDirectory();
```

and this will list all folders on current drive

**EDIT**

`$folders = glob($sub . '/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);` will get all the folders in specified directory.

`foreach($folders as $folder)` will loop over `folders` array.

`$sub` will be the folder name that will be explored.

so, these are the folders

> A B C

`$folders` will have like `$folders['A', 'B', 'C']`

and in loop, each `A B and C` will be passed as `$sub` to check either it has more `folders` in it or not.

Comment: That did the job. Thanks ! Can i ask you how this function work ? Why is the scanDirectory at this end and what is the role of $sub in your code ? (in my code this variable was out of context i simply forgot to remove it)

Comment: Thanks that was helpful ! So if my understanding of this function is right, everytime scanDirectory finds a new folder, the value of $folder is erased by the new one, is that right ? What I'm trying to do is having this function compare every $folder found with the current repertory the user is in, and if it matches it would echo some html. This might need its own thread tho. Thanks a lot for your help anyway, was really helpful  !

Comment: @apatik: yes, it'll update the value of `$folder` on each iteration